# How does while loop know to move to the next block of info?

Tags: python, while-loop, urllib

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error

img = urllib.request.urlopen('http://data.pr4e.org/cover3.jpg')
fhand = open('cover3.jpg', 'wb')
size = 0
while True:
    info = img.read(100000)
    if len(info) < 1: break
    size = size + len(info)
    fhand.write(info)

print(size, 'characters copied.')
fhand.close()
```

How does this while loop know to move to the next block of 100000 bytes? I understand that in for loops, the loop moves forward through data. My understanding of while loops was that they do the same thing over and over unless told otherwise. I am not seeing where the loop is instructed not to read the same 100000 bytes over and over.

For reference, this is simply an example in chapter 12 in Python for Everybody.

Thanks!!!

Comment: `img` is actually a tcp/ip socket which streams data. Its whole job is to make sure you get each byte in turn without repeating anything and without skipping anything. So when your program asks for the first `100000` bytes it gives you all of them and next time round it is duty bound not to give you any of those again.

Comment: @quamrana so even though .read() is within a while loop, it continues forward due to being a data stream? My understand was that, such as is the case with the variable 'size', you needed to continuously add the old to the new `size = size + len(info)` within the loop or you would be overwriting the old information.

Comment: Not sure what you're expecting to hear from us here. The obvious answer is "`urllib` is programmed to remember where you stopped reading".

Comment: I mean, how else is it supposed to work? If it always gives you data you haven't seen before, then it must remember where you left off. That much has to be obvious to anybody. So I don't understand what kind of answers you want. Do you want to know how urllib does that internally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `read()` function will read the 100000 bytes and move the pointer to the end of that. So during the next `read()`, it will read from the 100001 byte. As a result, it is not reading the same 100000 bytes over and over